# Vertical-align and fill the remaining space of 3 blocks

Tags: css

I need to vertical-align 3 blocks, where the center block should take the remaining space, and lateral blocks are autosized.

My code ([PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvpXvw?editors=110)):

```css
.parent {
  background: lightgray;
  //display: table;
}

[class|="i"] {
  display: inline-block;
  //display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

.i-left {
  background: green;
}

.i-full {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 30%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.i-right {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="i-left">[min space left long size]</div>
    <div class="i-full">
        [long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill the row]
    </div>
    <div class="i-right">[min space right]</div>
</div>
```

=== **Restrictions**

- any fixed dimension should be imposed;
- lateral blocks widht is variable and **autosized** (the variant with **`table`** s that is commented-out does not respect this point);
- any `flex` should be used (because fo IE9 incompatibility);
- blocks should be vertically middle-aligned;
- blocks can ve whatever (inline, table, cell etc...).

Comment: Looks like a case for CSS tables to me.

Comment: with table I can't autosize the lateral cells..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS tables for the layout and `white-space:nowrap` on the "autosize" left/right cells so the text doesn't wrap.

```css
.parent {
  background: lightgray;
  display: table;
}
[class|="i"] {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.i-left {
  background: green;
  white-space: nowrap
}
.i-full {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.i-right {
  background: lightblue;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="i-left">[min space left long size]</div>
  <div class="i-full">
    [long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill the row long content to fill
    the row]
  </div>
  <div class="i-right">[min space right]</div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/NGXmbW)

Comment: helped your `white-space:nowrap`... ) remark, thanks!